# How to make PHP see a datetime value for what it is

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm passing the following value via URL to PHP:

```
&newtimestamp=2016-12-21%2014:44:44.
```

Instead of `%20` I've tried with `+`.

In PHP I have this:

```
$newtimestamp = $_GET["newtimestamp"];
```

Which correctly shows the timestamp if I do:

```
echo ($newtimestamp);
```

But when trying:

```
echo date_format($newtimestamp,'U');
```

or

```
echo date_format($newtimestamp,'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I get no output at all. And later in the script, the input is used to compare against an SQL table:

```
$sql = ("SELECT sender,subject,timestamp,threadid,username,notify,msgtype FROM Messages WHERE sender = '$usernametmp' AND subject !=''  AND timestamp > '$newtimestamp' ORDER BY timestamp");
```

And I get no results at all.

I do get results If I manually set the timestamp to

```
$newtimestamp = '1985-10-07 11:42:12';
```

I was thinking that I need to define it as datetime with:

```
$timestamp = new DateTime($newtimestamp);
```

But then I get a server error. 
PHP version is 5.3, by the way. and needs to be changed by my hosting provider. If that's the solution, is there a lot of stuff running with 5.3 that will no longer work with 5.5 or 5.6 (this is what they offer)?

I hope someone can see what I'm doing wrong here, thanks in advance!

Comment: What error specifically do you get with `new DateTime()`? enable display_errors with `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`.  To get PHP to interpret that string as a date, you can use `new DateTime($newtimestamp)` for  a DateTime object, or `strtotime($newtimestamp)` to get a Unix timestamp value.  And what is the data type of your `timestamp` column in the MySQL table? Is it a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` type or is it an integer type?  Simply comparing the string `$newtimestamp` should work ( except that it's vulnerable to SQL injection)

Comment: `date_format()` returns a formatted string from a `DateTime` object, so your input string must first be converted to an object then passed as the 1st param.  That is the reason you saw no output -  `display_errors` must not be enabled and PHP would be issuing a notice related to an invalid date string.

Comment: php `date_format` function parameter is a date object not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `date_create` function and decode the URL on the `GET` like this:

```
<?php
$newtimestamp=date_create(urldecode($_GET['newtimestamp']));
echo date_format($newtimestamp,"Y/m/d H:i:s");
```

Comment: Explain what he did wrong and why this solves his problem, otherwise it's just a piece of code...

Comment: I tried that now, with a few amendment:
    $newtime=date_create(urldecode($_GET['newtimestamp']));
    $newtimestamp = date_format($newtime,"Y/m/d H:i:s");

That helped a bit: The SQL returns all messages newer than the incoming date if it´s set to BEFORE the last message of 2016, but if I set the incoming time to for instance 2016-12-25+14:44:00, after which there were no messages entered in 2016, I will NOT see the messages from 2017!!
(sorry, couldn´t edit the previous message which I sent off too fast).

Comment: Allright what I did was right, I just had a minor glitch somewhere else in the script. So since this is based on Jade´s answer, that´s indeed the one that sorted this out for me, thanks (to everybody else as well of course!)!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare human time to unix time format, unix time looks like this

> 1483319956

So you probably need a function to help you do that

try this custom function i wrote

```
change_date_to_timestamp($date_string)
{
    $array = explode(' ', $date_string);
    $date = $array[0];
    $date = explode('-', $date);
    $year = (int)$date[0];
    $month = (int)$date[1];
    $day = (int)$date[2];
    $hour = 00;
    $minute = 00;
    $second = 00;

    if (isset($array[1])) {
        $time = $array[1];
        $time = explode(':', $time);
        $hour = (int)$time[0];
        $minute = (int)$time[1];
        $second = (int)$time[2];
    }


    $stamp = mktime($hour, $minute, $second, $month, $day, $year);

    return $stamp;
}
```

Refactor as pleased

Comment: Thanks, but I´m not after a unix version of the timestamp. I only added those to show that the incoming timestamp is not being seen as a timestamp by php. I was assuming that if that´d be the case, it´d show me the timestamp in unix format.